# After I reinstalled Android Studio, many resources are kinda missing

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I reinstalled Android Studio, because one of my drives crashed.
After the installation I tried to build my project, I got some strange errors:

```
C:\Users\woors\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-
27.0.2.aar\c3f1a01ea2c7c2b45168cff946884206\res\values\values.xml
Error:error: resource layout/abc_alert_dialog_material (aka com.tomade.saufomat:layout/abc_alert_dialog_material) not found.
Error:error: resource layout/abc_select_dialog_material (aka com.tomade.saufomat:layout/abc_select_dialog_material) not found.
Error:error: resource layout/select_dialog_item_material (aka com.tomade.saufomat:layout/select_dialog_item_material) not found.
Error:error: resource layout/select_dialog_multichoice_material (aka com.tomade.saufomat:layout/select_dialog_multichoice_material) not found.
Error:error: resource layout/select_dialog_singlechoice_material (aka com.tomade.saufomat:layout/select_dialog_singlechoice_material) not found.
Error:error: resource anim/abc_popup_enter (aka com.tomade.saufomat:anim/abc_popup_enter) not found.
Error:error: resource anim/abc_popup_exit (aka com.tomade.saufomat:anim/abc_popup_exit) not found.
Error:error: resource anim/abc_grow_fade_in_from_bottom (aka com.tomade.saufomat:anim/abc_grow_fade_in_from_bottom) not found.
Error:error: resource anim/abc_shrink_fade_out_from_bottom (aka com.tomade.saufomat:anim/abc_shrink_fade_out_from_bottom) not found.
Error:error: resource anim/tooltip_enter (aka com.tomade.saufomat:anim/tooltip_enter) not found.
Error:error: resource anim/tooltip_exit (aka com.tomade.saufomat:anim/tooltip_exit) not found.
Error:error: resource color/abc_btn_colored_borderless_text_material (aka com.tomade.saufomat:color/abc_btn_colored_borderless_text_material) not found.
Error:error: resource color/abc_btn_colored_text_material (aka com.tomade.saufomat:color/abc_btn_colored_text_material) not found.
Error:error: resource drawable/abc_list_selector_holo_dark (aka com.tomade.saufomat:drawable/abc_list_selector_holo_dark) not found.
Error:error: resource color/abc_background_cache_hint_selector_material_dark (aka com.tomade.saufomat:color/abc_background_cache_hint_selector_material_dark) not found.
Error:error: resource color/abc_primary_text_material_dark (aka com.tomade.saufomat:color/abc_primary_text_material_dark) not found.
Error:error: resource color/abc_primary_text_material_light (aka com.tomade.saufomat:color/abc_primary_text_material_light) not found.
Error:error: resource color/abc_primary_text_disable_only_material_dark (aka com.tomade.saufomat:color/abc_primary_text_disable_only_material_dark) not found.
Error:error: resource color/abc_secondary_text_material_dark (aka com.tomade.saufomat:color/abc_secondary_text_material_dark) not found.
Error:error: resource color/abc_secondary_text_material_light (aka com.tomade.saufomat:color/abc_secondary_text_material_light) not found.
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt
```

I cleaned my cache and tried to build again, but I get the same errors.
Has anyone experiences with this error?

---

**UPDATE**:
If I delete the file
`\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml`
the error is gone. But just for a few minutes. Then I have to delete the file again.
And everytime I start Android Studio I have to reselect my SDK.
These Errors are really strange.

Comment: clean -> rebuild or invalidate caches and restart

Comment: You might also need to delete the build cache by hand.

Comment: I deleted everything in C:\Users\woors\.gradle\caches\ but the error is still there :/

Comment: Did you have a different version of `compileSdkVersion` and `buildToolsVersion`? Try using the same version with the support library which is 27.

Comment: @ישואוהבאותך Ty that worked
I had compiledSdkVersion 27 and buildToolsVersion 26

Comment: If you try using buildToolsVersion `27.0.3` is it still works? If it works, let me make it at answer and then you can close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have different version of `CompileSdkVersion`, `buildToolsVersion`, `targetSdkVersion`, and support library. You need to use the same version for them. In your case, you need to use version 27. Something like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 27
  buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 27
    // ...
  }

  //...
}

dependencies {

  // ...
  implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'

}
```